# How to handle arrays sent from jquery ajax with traditional : false

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a bit of fun passing arrays from jquery ajax to a MVC .Net controller.

I have a couple parameters that I need to provide - here is the signature of the controller method:

```
public PartialViewResult GetMyPartial(Dictionary<int, string> param1, IEnumerable<int> param2)
```

For some reason I can't get param2 to be passed to the server.  On the client in JS I'm building the collections in the following manner:

```
var param1 = {};
$.each(someIntArray, function (index, value) {
    param1[value] = 'test' + index;
});

var param2 = [];
$('.someCheckbox[aria-expanded|=true]').each(function () {
    param2.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
});
```

I'm sending them in the following manner:

```
$.ajax({
...
    //traditional: true,
    data: {
        param1: param1,
        param2: param2
    },
...
});
```

This successfully passes param1, but not param2.  If I uncomment the `traditional: true` then param2 is passed successfully, but not param1.

Is there a way to use the traditional mode on a single parameter?  Or some way to get the controller to be happy with `?param2[]=1&param2[]=2`.  At the moment it only seems to like `?param2=1&param2=2`.

I suspect that it may be down to how I'm building the collections which is why I've included that code.

Any help would be great - thank in advance.

Comment: Would it be easier for you to post actual json than `?param2[]=1&param2[]=2` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to send JSON, you could do

```
    data: JSON.stringify({
        param1: param1,
        param2: param2
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not hitting the controller method at all - unless you're suggesting I change the signature of that too?

Also, the `dataType` refers to the result of the call I believe, which needs to be HTML since the controller should return a chunk of HTML